# initialize multiple bools in c++

Tags: c++, boolean

I have some input flags in a C++ program, they all start out false.  I thought it might be nice, if I could initialize all of them to false. So I tried:

```
bool flagA, flagB, flagH = false;
```

but the flags did not get set properly, when I tried this. flagA evidently was initialized as true?
Setting the flags explicitly works.

```
bool flagA = false;
bool flagB = false;
bool flagH = false;
```

I am using g++, and I do not get compiler errors or warnings. I know the program is misbehaving because flagA when set true sends program output to the local printer. Just wondering.

Comment: If you declare them as global scope then all start with false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When compiler sees `bool flagA, flagB, flagH = false;` he translates is as

> User needs three `bool` values, named `flagA`, `flagB` and `flagC`. Oh, and `flagC` shall be initialized to `false`.

It's just shorter writing for

```
bool flagA;
bool flagB;
bool flagC = false;
```

And since they are local scope variables (probably), they are not guaranteed to be initialized with default value.

Comment: In C++, bools are objects right? So, won't the default contructor kick in and initialize to 0?

Comment: @nirvanaswap In C++, `bool` is not object and no default construction happens.  But you can force default initialization using `bool flagA{};`.